# Date time display timezone as time - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm passing some data from an API which has the date formatted as such:

```
2016-08-30T00:00:00-16:00
```

The time zone is the actual time (-16:00) - I have no idea why, and when I display this time using strftime it always picks up the 00:00:00.

```
<%= @date.strftime("%d %b, %Y") + ' @ ' + @date.strftime("%I:%M%P") %>
```

Displays

```
30 Aug, 2016 @ 12:00am
```

How can I display the timezone part as the time? I have looked at:

```
%z - Time zone as hour offset from UTC (e.g. +0900)
```

But doesn't display it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
date = "2016-08-30T00:00:00-16:00".to_time.utc # you can use your date object insted of static time

<%= date.strftime("%d %b, %Y") + ' @ ' + date.strftime("%I:%M%P") %>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks @hardik.

Comment: Welcome @DollarChills